# Unable to boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 14 (Dual hard disk, dual boot system)

Tags: boot, windows-7

This is my first time trying to install Ubuntu; I am more familiar with using Macs.

I had my Windows 7 pre-installed upon receiving a new desktop (Acer Veriton with Intel i7 Processor, 32GB, 1TB HDD and 256GB SSD). Windows 7 was installed on the SSD, so I went ahead with installing Ubuntu onto the HDD. I used a DVD with Ubuntu written on it and booted from the removable disk drive (by changing the option on BIOS option page). I mostly followed instructions I found from several threads here such as creating "/, /home, /swap" (I am planning to do some intensive data processing). I then selected the option of booting from 'sdb' which was the HDD that I was installing Ubuntu on. 'sda' is the SSD with Windows.

However when I restarted my computer, I was able to successfully boot to Ubuntu, but when I tried to change back to booting from Windows (located on the SSD), I could not do so. I was brought to a black screen with 'Windows Error Recovery' indicating that Windows files were 'damaged or configured incorrectly'. I tried to Launch Startup Repair (recommended), but would be brought back repeatedly to this screen i.e. it did not work. So I tried to Start Windows Normally, but was brought to a second page stating 'Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected device and press a key'.

**Picture links:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPeuK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnxef.jpg

I am not sure what exactly I did wrong. Would greatly appreciate any help as I am extremely worried that I may have to re-install everything again.

Comment: we need more info about install and hardware...it sounds like you have one of those ~stupid (IMO)~ rapid accelerator caches that complicates ALL installs...and although it is a good idea in some instances, you can see how it can cause more problems than it is worth.  I may still be able to advise despite the fact I have no hands on experience with these specific setups.  I knew that it would be a problem and for this reason have advised clients against them.

Comment: Can you specify what sort of information you would need? @user175999

Comment: Update: When I tried to run boot-repair, it told me to boot into EFI mode as I was in Legacy mode. Could the problem be because I have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode whereas Windows was installed in EFI mode? Windows was installed upon arrival so I can't be sure. However, I did a print summary from boot-repair that may be helpful: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11422788/

Comment: Looked through your boot-repair log...its quite a mess (not your fault) as I expected.  There are two main objectives I have with my advice that I am going to give.  1. I want your windows install to stay as operative as possible. 2. I want you to be able to boot into ubuntu with as little time, data loss, frustration, etc.  As long as you know that and are willing to continue we can.  #1 tip backup anything important #2 yes you want to go back into efi mode but you must ensure your Ubuntu install will install from EFI mode. Post again when you have an update. I'm out of characters.